# Marking/Annotating lines with symbols (with external storage)

Tags: comments, plugin-vim-commentary

When I audit code I perform a lot of annotations/mark lines. (what audited, by whom, if we have open issue, etc etc...).

When I work with code I would like to mark lines (both individually and ranges), with some symbol (can be ascii, unicode would be awesome).

I would like this information to be stored in same way that I can later import/export with my scripts (in other programming languages).

How this could ideally look like:

```
*  1 This
?  2 is
T  3 test
!  4 file.

-- INSERT --     4,6  All
```

OR on the right side of numbers

```
  1* This
  2? is
  3T test
  4! file.

-- INSERT --     4,6  All
```

When I was searching for plugins the most promising I've found was:
https://github.com/plutonly/vim-annotate ,
but does not do the job actually... as it only annotates when folded and I need to have it unfolded.

Again, as I need/want to integrate this information with other systems, I hope that this information would be stored in persistent way so I could programatically find it and read/write.

((I am using Vim8 but also fine with NeoVim.))

FTR. I am programmer so I can write import/export. I just don't know Vim programming well enough to make whole thing. If there would be similar project, maybe I could modify it/adopt it.

UPDATE: As I can not find a way to display symbols ( [Display extra column before/after line numbers and modify using Vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/35029/7263) ) I started prototyping with higlighting ( [Generate relatively unique "cache filename" for given file path (like swap files do)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/35030/7263) )

Comment: You can place signs, but you'd have to do serialization/de-serialization yourself, AFAIK

Comment: Thank you ! After you writing `:help sign`  in another comment I understood that by "signs" you meant that there is command `sing`. I am so new to vimscripting, that I didn't get it from this comment :) . http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html#:sign