# Display extra column before/after line numbers and modify using Vimscript

Tags: vimscript

How to display extra column before/after line numbers , and modify , programmatically, using Vimscript?

Maybe some examples of existing plugins doing so, that I could base of?

(this could be great basis/start for [Marking/Annotating lines with symbols (with external storage)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/35012/7263) )

```
*  1 This
?  2 is
T  3 test
!  4 file.

-- INSERT --     4,6  All
```

OR on the right side of numbers

```
  1* This
  2? is
  3T test
  4! file.

-- INSERT --     4,6  All
```

Comment: Please see `:help sign` (if I got the reference right), which I indirectly alluded to in my comment on your other very similar Q.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it ! Thank you! You mean http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html#:sign .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @d-ben-knoble [`:help sign`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html#:sign) is the answer + making sure you do not have turned on merging line number and sign column in your `.vimrc` (check for `signcolumn` in your `.vimrc` files).

From [`:help sign`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html#:sign)  :

```
:sign define piet text=>> texthl=Search
:exe ":sign place 2 line=23 name=piet file=" . expand("%:p")
" and
:sign unplace 2
" or
:sign unplace all
```

If you want to see example of `vimscript` snippet using it, here is my current version of snippet in `.vimrc`

```
" ################
sign define byA text=+A

" Highlights lines specified in file
" call using :call HL()
function! HL()
  execute 'sign unplace * file='.expand('%:p')
  for i in readfile($HOME.'/.cache/HL/l.txt')
    "echom 'Highlighting '.i
    call matchadd('LineHighlight', '\%'.i.'l')
    execute ':sign place '.(123000+i).' line='.i.' name=byA file='.expand('%:p')
  endfor
endfunction

" Adds current line to file
function! AddLineToHL()
    silent execute '! echo '.line('.').' | tee -a '.$HOME.'/.cache/HL/l.txt'
    call HL()
    redraw!
endfunction
" and add shortcut (usually [\]+[l])
nnoremap <Leader>l :call AddLineToHL()<CR>

" ###############
```